# Raspberry pi - ubuntu mate

Tags: 64-bit, raspberrypi, 32-bit, ubuntu-mate

I have a simple question.
Can I run Ubuntu Mate 20.04 64 bit on a raspberry pi 3 32 bit?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Raspberry Pi 3 has a 64 bit `arm64` processor. It supports both the 32 bit (`armhf`) as well as the 64 bit (`arm64`) images of Ubuntu MATE.

[image]
 <sup>[Image source](https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/compatibility/)</sup>

However, according to the [download page](https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/download/), armhf (32 bit) images may work better on models with less than 2 GB RAM, like the Pi3/3+.